# How to enter an account directly at start up

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, login, startup

How do you get an account to log in automatically on power up? The idea is the computer is turned on remotely through a power switch, boots up and then automatically logs into the user account. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Xubuntu as my GUI on a RaspberryPi 2.

So far, all I have found is how to remove the requirements for a password to login, but you still need to physically click "log in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default logins depends on your Display Manager. You can know which one you use by using this command:

```
# cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

Then, you need to edit the configuration file of your display manager: gdm.conf or kdmrc or ... There is a comment part which explains how to use  the autologin.

On my ubuntu, I see a comment in the file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf :

```
# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1
```

I just have to uncomment to enable it.